# How to replace hamburger icon with "Menu" text?

Tags: menus

My client has asked me to replace the hamburger icon in the mobile menu with the text "Menu", because he finds it more intuitive.

I'm using the WordPress theme Kumle. In the file "assets/third-party/meanmenu/jquery.meanmenu.js", I managed to find a setting that allows me to define the text that is displayed when the menu is closed:

```
meanMenuOpen: "MENU", // text/markup you want when menu is closed
```

However, the text "Menu" only appears after clicking once and then closing the menu. Before clicking, it's blank. Even the hamburger doesn't appear now.

Below is part of the css code that controls the menu:

```
.mean-container a.meanmenu-reveal {
    color: #1e435a;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    font-size: 1px;
    font-weight: 700;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    padding: 20px 15px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-indent: -9999em;
    top: 0;
    width: 27px;
}
.mean-container a.meanmenu-reveal span {
    background: #fff;
    display: block;
    height: 1px;
    margin-top: 8px
}
a.meanmenu-reveal.meanclose {
    color:#fff;
}
.mean-container .mean-nav {
    background:#2c4450;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 60px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9999999;
}   
.mean-container .mean-nav ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    list-style-type: none;
}

.mean-container .mean-nav ul li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
```

And below are the variables present in the js:

```
var defaults = {
                    meanMenuTarget: jQuery(this), // Target the current HTML markup you wish to replace
                    meanMenuContainer: 'body', // Choose where meanmenu will be placed within the HTML
                    meanMenuClose: "X", // single character you want to represent the close menu button
                    meanMenuCloseSize: "18px", // set font size of close button
                    meanMenuOpen: "MENU", // text/markup you want when menu is closed
                    meanRevealPosition: "right", // left right or center positions
                    meanRevealPositionDistance: "0", // Tweak the position of the menu
                    meanRevealColour: "", // override CSS colours for the reveal background
                    meanScreenWidth: "480", // set the screen width you want meanmenu to kick in at
                    meanNavPush: "", // set a height here in px, em or % if you want to budge your layout now the navigation is missing.
                    meanShowChildren: true, // true to show children in the menu, false to hide them
                    meanExpandableChildren: true, // true to allow expand/collapse children
                    meanExpand: "+", // single character you want to represent the expand for ULs
                    meanContract: "-", // single character you want to represent the contract for ULs
                    meanRemoveAttrs: false, // true to remove classes and IDs, false to keep them
                    onePage: false, // set to true for one page sites
                    meanDisplay: "block", // override display method for table cell based layouts e.g. table-cell
                    removeElements: "" // set to hide page elements             };
```

If necessary, I can provide the link to the site to check the problem live. Then you'll have to click on the right-hand corner of the red bar below "choose your language". This will expand the mobile menu. When you close it, the text "Menu" will appear, but I need the text to be there since the first load.

Comment: Maybe just use jQuery to replace HTML?

Comment: @mysticalghoul I'm not very familiar with jQuery. However, I've been searching for a solution based on your suggestion and it seems like this function only works when the user clicks a button. I mean, it only replaces what needs to be replaced once a button is clicked. That wouldn't solve the problem since I need the "Menu" to be there right from the start. Am I getting this wrong?

Comment: Well you can run the jQuery function on page load to replace the icon with text like this: $("class or id of target element").html('Menu');